# Is there a library to programmatically convert a PDF document into a flipping book?

Tags: pdf, automation, flash

I would like to convert programmatically convert a PDF document to a Flash flipping book.

The same thing is done throug this site : http://www.codebox.es/pdf-to-flash-page-flip

They apparently use those 2 libraries :

- Dynamic Page Flip v2 from [76design.com](http://76design.com/shiftcontrol/index.php/2006/08/22/dynamic-page-flip-v2/)
- SWFTools from [swftools.org](http://www.swftools.org/)

Is there any existing code to do the same job programmatically ?

Or do I have to develop in starting with these 2 projects ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FlexPaper Zine which can be used with swftools has been released quite recently and looks good with HTML5 support for devices. It programmatically publishes documents using php or any other server language of choice

http://flexpaper.devaldi.com/flexpaper_flip_zine.jsp

Comment: I want other tool like this, but free.